# Triggering an event in VB based on a change in a control in a group box

Tags: vb.net

I have a group box with multiple Checkboxes(food item) and each one has a corresponding NumericUpDown control(quantity). For context, it is for a project based on a restaurant menu. I want to hide a button called btnSave whenever either a checkbox is unchecked or the quantity (NumericUpDown) is changed. I currently have `btnSave.Hide` under the `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged` and `NumericUpDown1_CheckedChanged` SubProcedures but I want to know if there's a way to do this when anything within this group box is changed instead of putting the code under each SubProcedure. Thanks

Comment: You can use one event handler to handle as many events as you want.  Look at the Handles keyword in the event method declaration, just add more control names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant `.ValueChanged` for the `NumericUpDown` control. (There is no `.CheckedChanged`) Although this doesn't matter much in this case, this is a good pattern for future reference. Instead of calling an event call a Sub from your events.

When you have several controls responding to a single Event handler, you can find out which control triggered the event by checking the sender parameter. Since, as you can see, `sender` is an `Object` you will have to cast it to the appropriate type to get the properties of a `CheckBox`.

```
Private Sub HideSaveButton()
    btnSave.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxInGroupBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    HideSaveButton()
    Dim WhichCheckBox As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Select Case WhichCheckBox.Name
        Case "CheckBox1"
            MessageBox.Show("CheckBox1 has changed")
        Case "CheckBox2"
            MessageBox.Show("CheckBox2 has changed")
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    HideSaveButton()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Mary, Thanks so much for that its exactly what I was looking for. I actually have `.ValueChanged` in my code I just mistyped here. Thanks again